Apple Script Automatic Response to Email
I have a contact me form on my website. A visitor fills out their name, email, subject, and message. I receive an email with the following info:
From: contact@mywebsite.com
To: contact@mywebsite.com
Subject: New submission with subject: Example Subject
Reply-To: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>

Hello,

Someone has just submitted a new form on your website.

Name: John Doe

Email: [john.doe@example.com](mailto:john.doe@example.com)

Subject: Example Subject

Content:

This is a test form submission. 

Every email I receive is exactly like this. How would I create a macOS mail rule using an apple script to automatically reply to this email: (I know how to make the rule and select the script, I just can’t get any of the dozen scripts I’ve made to work)
From: contact@mywebsite.com
To: john.doe@example.com
Subject: Re: Example Subject

John,

Thank you for contacting me. I will respond as soon as I am able.

[automatically select and add my signature I have created for the contact@mywebsite.com address]

I'm open to even having the apple script just take the body of the email and send to a python or bash script to process this and then create the email and send it.

Consider building in steps, and then post the results of your steps, both those that work and up to the step that fails. Step 1 might be to not use AppleScript at all, but just make a rule that automatically replies (this would not be able to be personalized, but it would make sure that your rule for catching incoming mail is correct). Step 2 would then be to do the same thing with a script—no personalization, just a simple reply. Only then would you proceed to step 3, personalizing the reply.

I just stuck to what I know. Python. I wrote a python script to do everything I wanted and just run the python script from the apple script. Unfortunately, all that macOS Mail app will allow for a rule is an apple script; therefore, the apple script is a simple one, it just executes my python script.

Use the "do shell script" applescript command: do shell script "python your/path/program.py"
